# print all nodes at a distance of 'x' from a given node in BST

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

The detailed question is to find all the nodes with distance x( i.e. number of edges =x) from a given node .

I was asked in an Amazon Interview today,

```
void findNodeWithDistanceX(struct node* root,struct node * qnode, int value)
{
    //root is root Node, qnode is questionnode from which distance to be calculated, value is the            
    //distance to be calculated


    //finding distance between root and qnode
    int distance = findDistancefromRoot(root ,qnode);

    if(distance> value)
    {
        traverseDistancedown(root ,distance-value);
    }

    if(distance ==value){
        printf("%d",root->value);
    }

    // Traverse and find all nodes with distance value from 'qnode' down the tree
    traverseDistancedown(qnode,value);
```

Now In case of finding the distance "value"  from qnode .
I did not get the answer how to traverse up the Tree and satisfy the condition of distance with value.

Although many cases arises here.

I tried backtracking from qnode but to no avail I was unable to impress him and unable to write the Code.

Any Discussion regarding implementing the traversal up the tree will be helpful to me.

Comment: breadth-first search?

Comment: By the way, please format your code... I hope this is not the version you presented in the interview

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is with a depth-first search, keeping track of the distance as you go along. It's a simple pre-order traversal starting at the "question node".

```
void nodesAtDistance(struct node* qnode, int requestedDistance, int currentDistance)
{
    if (qnode == null) return;

    if (currentDistance == requestedDistance)
    {
        // output qnode
        // and then return because children are further away
        return;
    }

    // visit left and then right
    nodesAtDistance(qnode->left, requestedDistance, currentDistance+1);
    nodesAtDistance(qnode->right, requestedDistance, currentDistance+1);
}
```

So if you call this with:

```
nodesAtDistance(myNode, 5, 0);
```

It will output all nodes that are 5 levels below `myNode`.

Now, if I were to write this as an API function, I would provide an overload that doesn't require the client to pass that `currentDistance` parameter. Because if somebody were to write `nodesAtDistance(myNode, 5, 1)`, you'd get things at distance 4. So, create this overload:

```
void nodesAtDistance(node * qnode, int requestedDistance)
{
    nodesAtDistance(qnode, requestedDistance, 0);
}
```

Make that function publicly visible, and make the other one private.

Comment: I know this is old, but this doesn't answer the question asked by the poster : "how to traverse up the Tree and satisfy the condition of distance with value ?" You're only going down the tree, whereas you need also to find nodes at a distance k up in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, although this code checks only for children nodes and does not go back to check on ancestors nodes at given distance

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<malloc.h>

    struct treenode
    {
     unsigned int data;
     struct treenode *left;
     struct treenode *right;
    };

    struct treenode  *treeptr, *sourcenode, *quesnode, *quesleftnode, *quesrightnode, *root =          NULL;

    struct node *treeptr insert_node(unsigned int treedata)
    {
      treeptr= (struct node*)(malloc(sizeof(treenode)));
      treeptr->data = nodevalue;
      treeptr->left   = NULL;
      treeptr->right = NULL;    
      return treeptr;
   }

   printnodesdistancek(struct treenode* quesnode, unsigned char reqdist)
   {
     unsigned char curdist=0;
     do
     {
      if(quesnode == null)
      return;

      quesleftnode = quesnode->left;

       if(curdist == reqdist)
       {
         printf("%d",quesleftnode->data);
       } 
       else
       {
        quesnode= quesnode->left;
       }
       quesrightnode = quesnode->right;

      if(curdist == reqdist)
      {
        printf("%d",quesrightnode->data);
      }
      else
      {
       quesnode = quesnode->right;
      }
      }while(quesnode!=NULL);
      //main function
      void main(void)
      {
       //create tree

       *root = insert_node(1);
        root->left=insert_node(-1);
        root->right=insert_node(2);
        root->left->left=insert_node(-2);
        root->left->right=insert_node(3);
        root->right->left=insert_node(-3);
        root->right->right=insert_node(4);
        sourcenode = root->left;
        printnodesdistancek(sourcenode,1);

      }
```